# Ionic Cordova Typescript iOS App - Automatically retrieving data from BLE

Tags: ios, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have below rudimentary understanding of Typescript as I'm NOT a programmer...

I have managed to to compile and run the sample app "connect" from the Ionic/Cordova BLE Central plugin - https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central - and I'm able to scan nearby BLE devices and connect to them.

I have further managed to write my own function that enables me to send data TO the device I'm connecting to (an Arduino Mega with a HM-10 BLE attached).

```
  onBtnPress(peripheral) {
      var data = new Uint8Array(1);
      data[0] = 50;    
      this.ble.writeWithoutResponse(this.peripheral.id, 'FFE0', 'FFE1', data.buffer);
      console.log("Sending: " + data[0]);

  }
```

I'm fairly confident I can write a function that can retrieve data from the device, every time I would invoke that function (like pushing a button). HOWEVER, what I'm really looking for is to be able to receive the data as it is sent (random intervals) and be able to display it.

```
this.ble.read(this.peripheral.id, 'FFE0', 'FFE1', data.buffer);
```

Is there such a thing in Typescript as a subscription where I can get notified anytime there's data being sent to the app? And if so, what would such a function look like?

Comment: `Peripheral` does not broadcast data (only protocol packet like iBeacon eg.) unless you connect `Central` (your iOS device) to it and request the data explicitly (which you highlighted).  Hence I am not sure I understand your need for `subscription with random intervals`.  You can  `setInterval()` to request poll data at `same` intervals.

Comment: So the application is a game for my son that is initiated via a mobile app (hence we send a small command eg Game # to be played). It takes a random amount of time for the game to finish, at the end of which the Arduino sends a Serial.write(your time was XXX seconds) which needs to be captured back on the iOS app. Since there is no synchronization from the Arduino sending to iOS receiving, I'm hoping there's a way to 'subscribe' to data coming from the Arduino side. Is that more clear?

Comment: With simple read/write it won't work IMHO. For this you would need to poll the arduino and store the game "status" so that Central can ask for updates in set intervals. For your model you should explore Publish/Subscribe or MQTT comm. Eg. something like https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CurieBLE